# How to fill larger image into smaller div?

Tags: html, css

I want to put 1/3 larger image into a smaller div and rectangle is centering but I don't know how to fill in.

Here is an example:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4omxxhmy/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class='outer'>
   <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/R/3/7/W/R/orange-vertical-rectangle-hi.png' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
.outer{
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  overflow : hidden;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background-color : black;
  margin : auto;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  z-index : -1;
  margin-left : -25%;
}
```

I just want upper 1/3 of orange rectangle into the outer div, and the rest of rectangle is hidden. In my example, i put the background-color to outer div for easier recognize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Remove `position: absolute;`  in img class

**Update css**

```
img{
  z-index : -1;
  margin-left : -25%;
}
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/yuhxqczc/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
*{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
.outer{
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  overflow : hidden;
  border-radius : 50%;
  background-color : black;
  margin : auto;
}
img{
  z-index : -1;
  margin-left : -25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
   <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/R/3/7/W/R/orange-vertical-rectangle-hi.png' />
</div>
```